# Woocommerce : Remove required field from form-edit-account.php

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I tried to remove firstname , lastname and email fields from form-edit-account.php in woocommerce but when I submit form I got some errors from woocommerce form validation!
how can I remove validation of this fields? i searching to much and check woocommerce hooks document , but I can't find anything about form-edit-account.php form validation and all of them is about checkout fields

https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/hook-docs.html
https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/introduction-to-hooks-actions-and-filters/
https://wpthememakeover.com/2016/07/21/how-to-remove-form-fields-in-woocommerce-account-page/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As on `/myaccount/form-edit-account.php` **the fields are hardcoded** in the template directly.

There is no hooks to remove, unset or hide this fields…

The best alternative for you should be to hide them with CSS…

For that you can add this CSS rule in the styles.css ile of your active theme:

```css
.woocommerce-account form.edit-account > p.woocommerce-form-row {
    display: none;
}
```

This will remove (hide) the fields… When customer will submit the form, there will not get any error **if those hidden fields have some data (hidden).**

This will only **avoid customer to make changes on his related own data**. He only will able to change password.

> You could remove them directly from the template, but all this fields **are really required to make WooCommerce/WordPress functional** as each registered user has a first name a last name **and especially an emai**…

Answer (score 8):

I just now did this exact thing myself and it worked like a charm.  I know your post is over a year old, but I hope it will help someone else, at least, because there are a lot of naysayers out there that told me it can not be done.  Took me 2 hours of trial and error (I'm not and expert by any means) and here it is...

### Step 1

In your child theme's functions.php file, add this code...

```
//Remove required field requirement for first/last name in My Account Edit form
    add_filter('woocommerce_save_account_details_required_fields', 'remove_required_fields');

        function remove_required_fields( $required_fields ) {
            unset($required_fields['account_first_name']);
            unset($required_fields['account_last_name']);

            return $required_fields;
        }
```

Now this merely removes the requirement of the user to fill-in a last and first name field, it does not remove the actual fields themselves from the form, but the form will be able to be submitted now even if the first and last name fields are left blank.

### Step 2

To remove the two fields from the form, go to **/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/myaccount/includes/** and download the form-edit-account.php file to your desktop.

Open the file and comment-out or remove the following block of code (should be lines 26 through 33, but don't rely on just line #s)...

```
<p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--first form-row form-row-first">
    <label for="account_first_name"><?php esc_html_e( 'First name', 'woocommerce' ); ?>&nbsp;<span class="required">*</span></label>
    <input type="text" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" name="account_first_name" id="account_first_name" autocomplete="given-name" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $user->first_name ); ?>" />
</p>
<p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--last form-row form-row-last">
    <label for="account_last_name"><?php esc_html_e( 'Last name', 'woocommerce' ); ?>&nbsp;<span class="required">*</span></label>
    <input type="text" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" name="account_last_name" id="account_last_name" autocomplete="family-name" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $user->last_name ); ?>" />
</p>
```

### Step 3

Then upload that file to your the following folder under you child theme...

**/wp-content/themes/YOUR CHILD THEME FOLDER/woocommerce/myaccount/**

and you're good to go!

### NOTICE

You are not uploading the file to **/wp-content/themes/YOUR CHILD THEME FOLDER/woocommerce/templates/myaccount/includes/** to match the plugin subfolders.  You have to use the subfolder string as stated above. That's the way it has to be and it says so right in the file notes :)  If you upload it to the subfolders to match the plugin subfolders where the original file resides, it won't work at all.

Comment: Can we remove `email` field with this approach? Because email is different field that required for sending order status changes. If you know a solution that makes email not required and causes no errors, please let us know about that. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[This is the guide you should be following](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters/). Do **not** directly edit `form-edit-account.php`. Add the code to remove those fields in your [custom functions file](https://codex.wordpress.org/Functions_File_Explained).

Example:

```
// Hook in
add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_address_fields' , 'custom_override_checkout_fields' );

// Our hooked in function - $fields is passed via the filter!
function custom_override_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
     unset($fields['billing']['billing_first_name']);

     return $fields;
}
```

Comment: this code will be remove filed from checkout or some where else ?

Comment: @M.D I apologize. I'm noticing now your specific question says that you'd like to remove it from the My Account page. Can you clarify if you want to remove this from My Account *and* the Checkout page? The code I provided removes it from both pages.

Comment: @micheal-t I just want to remove or hide from edit-account page or remove they "require" from validation

Answer (score 1):

There is a hidden caveat with "Chuck D" answer:
In file `class-wc-form-handler.php` of WooCommerce core, line 221:

```
    $account_first_name   = ! empty( $_POST['account_first_name'] ) ? wc_clean( wp_unslash( $_POST['account_first_name'] ) ) : '';
    $account_last_name    = ! empty( $_POST['account_last_name'] ) ? wc_clean( wp_unslash( $_POST['account_last_name'] ) ) : '';
    $account_display_name = ! empty( $_POST['account_display_name'] ) ? wc_clean( wp_unslash( $_POST['account_display_name'] ) ) : '';
    $account_email        = ! empty( $_POST['account_email'] ) ? wc_clean( wp_unslash( $_POST['account_email'] ) ) : '';
```

Which is looking for those fields values and if it doesn't find it, it assumes they are empty strings. That means if you use this method, every time you save user account details in the user's account page, WooCommerce empties the above fields.
The solution for this is to somehow get rid of the above lines or use the CSS trick that "LoicTheAztec" mentioned.

Comment: There is a way to override class-wc-form-handler.php. If anyone is interested, comment here.